# Segfault with large feature vector LibSVM

Tags: c++, android-ndk, libsvm, openframeworks

I am running LibSVM on an Android application (NDK). I have implemented similar code on a Mac application that works well for all feature vector sizes. When I give a vector of 408 features, I have no problems doing multi-class classification. Anything 409 or higher, though, and (I will eventually be putting in 16800) seems to fail here:

```
0-16 23:28:41.084 30997-31028/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xaf000000 in tid 31028 (GLThread 17147)
10-16 23:28:41.190 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1.1/LMY48M/2167285:user/release-keys'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: pid: 30997, tid: 31028, name: GLThread 17147  >>> cc.openframeworks.androidEmptyExample <<<
10-16 23:28:41.191 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xaf000000
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r0 aef3e000  r1 aef5ed10  r2 00000001  r3 af000000
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r4 aec29eb8  r5 00000001  r6 b4b2c608  r7 12d090c0
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     r8 12d15660  r9 b4a39400  sl 00000000  fp af37d824
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     ip b6e417dc  sp af37d810  lr a301ff78  pc a301ff04  cpsr 000f0010
10-16 23:28:41.202 27393-27393/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00167f04  /data/app/cc.openframeworks.androidEmptyExample-1/lib/arm/libOFAndroidApp.so (Kernel::dot(svm_node const*, svm_node const*)+192)
```

Here's the relevant code that I'm learning with:

```
ofxSvm mSvm;
void ofApp::update()
{ //Runs in loop            
    for(int i =0; i<8400; ++i)
    {
        HandDataVector.push_back((double)tempValue[i]);//tempValue is   incoming data from a serial port (8400 doubles per packet)
    }
    //If I exclude this I get segfaults:
    HandDataVector.resize(150);
    if(learningToggleBoxTicked)
    {
        mSvm.addData(HandDataVector,label)
        mSvm.train();
    } else {
        ofLogNotice("Classified As")<< mSvm.classify();
    }
}

int ofApp::classify()
{
    return mSvm.predict(HandDataVector);
}
```

Here's the ofxSvm Library I'm using

```
    int ofxSvm::addData(int label, vector<double>& vec)
    {
            checkDimension(vec.size());

            mData.insert(make_pair(label, vec));
            mDimension = vec.size();


            stringstream ss;
            for (const auto v : vec) ss << v << " ";
            ss << "EOS";
            ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "add data, label: " + ofToString(label) + " size: "+ofToString(vec.size())+" vec: " + ss.str());


            return mData.size();
   }
   void ofxSvm::train()
   {


            svm_problem prob;

            prob.l = mData.size();

            prob.y = new double[prob.l];
            {
                data_type::iterator it = mData.begin();
                int i = 0;
                while (it != mData.end())
                {
                    prob.y[i] = it->first;
                    ++it; ++i;
                }
            }


            if(mParam.gamma == 0)
            {
                mParam.gamma = 1.0 / mDimension;
            }

            int nodeLength = mDimension + 1;
            svm_node* node = new svm_node[prob.l * nodeLength];
            prob.x = new svm_node*[prob.l];
            {
                data_type::iterator it = mData.begin();
                int i = 0;
                while (it != mData.end())
                {
                    prob.x[i] = node + i * nodeLength;
                    for (int j = 0; j < mDimension; ++j)
                    {
                        prob.x[i][j].index = j + 1;
                        prob.x[i][j].value = it->second[j];
                    }
                    prob.x[i][mDimension].index = -1; // delimiter
                    ++it; ++i;
                }
            }

            ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "Start train...");

            mModel = svm_train(&prob, &mParam);



            ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "Finished train!");

            int x = mModel->nr_class;

            ofLogNotice("TRAINED MODEL LABELS: " + ofToString(x));

            delete[] node;
            delete[] prob.x;
            delete[] prob.y;
        }

        int ofxSvm::predict(vector<double>& testVec)
        {
            if (mModel == NULL)
            {
                ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "null model, before do train or load model file");
                return -5;
            }
            if (testVec.size() != mDimension)
            {
                ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "different dimension");
                return -6;
            }


            svm_node* node = new svm_node[mDimension + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < mDimension; ++i)
            {
                node[i].index = i + 1;
                node[i].value = testVec[i];
                ofLogNotice("node") << node[i].value <<"-" << i;

            }
            node[mDimension].index = -1;

            int res = static_cast<int>(svm_predict(mModel, node));


            stringstream ss;
            for (const auto v : testVec) ss << v << " ";
            ss << "EOS";
            ofLogNotice(LOG_MODULE, "add data, label: size: "+ofToString(testVec.size())+" vec: " + ss.str());


            ofLogNotice("ANSWER")<< res;


            delete[] node;
            return res;
    }
```

Here's the function in the LibSVM library the fault is happening in:

```
double Kernel::dot(const svm_node *px, const svm_node *py)
{
    double sum = 0;
    while(px->index != -1 && py->index != -1)
    {
        if(px->index == py->index)
        {
            sum += px->value * py->value;
            ++px;
            ++py;
        }
        else
        {
            if(px->index > py->index)
                ++py;
            else
                ++px;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

EDIT: Here's where the dot function is called (k_function in svm_predict_values)

```
double svm_predict_values(const svm_model *model, const svm_node *x, double* dec_values)
{
    int i;
    if(model->param.svm_type == ONE_CLASS ||
       model->param.svm_type == EPSILON_SVR ||
       model->param.svm_type == NU_SVR)
    {
        double *sv_coef = model->sv_coef[0];
        double sum = 0;
        for(i=0;i<model->l;i++)
            sum += sv_coef[i] * Kernel::k_function(x,model->SV[i],model->param);
        sum -= model->rho[0];
        *dec_values = sum;

        if(model->param.svm_type == ONE_CLASS)
            return (sum>0)?1:-1;
        else
            return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        int nr_class = model->nr_class;
        int l = model->l;

        double *kvalue = Malloc(double,l);
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            kvalue[i] = Kernel::k_function(x,model->SV[i],model->param);

        int *start = Malloc(int,nr_class);
        start[0] = 0;
        for(i=1;i<nr_class;i++)
            start[i] = start[i-1]+model->nSV[i-1];

        int *vote = Malloc(int,nr_class);
        for(i=0;i<nr_class;i++)
            vote[i] = 0;

        int p=0;
        for(i=0;i<nr_class;i++)
            for(int j=i+1;j<nr_class;j++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                int si = start[i];
                int sj = start[j];
                int ci = model->nSV[i];
                int cj = model->nSV[j];

                int k;
                double *coef1 = model->sv_coef[j-1];
                double *coef2 = model->sv_coef[i];
                for(k=0;k<ci;k++)
                    sum += coef1[si+k] * kvalue[si+k];
                for(k=0;k<cj;k++)
                    sum += coef2[sj+k] * kvalue[sj+k];
                sum -= model->rho[p];
                dec_values[p] = sum;

                if(dec_values[p] > 0)
                    ++vote[i];
                else
                    ++vote[j];
                p++;
            }

        int vote_max_idx = 0;
        for(i=1;i<nr_class;i++)
            if(vote[i] > vote[vote_max_idx])
                vote_max_idx = i;

        free(kvalue);
        free(start);
        free(vote);
        return model->label[vote_max_idx];
    }
}

double Kernel::k_function(const svm_node *x, const svm_node *y,
                          const svm_parameter& param)
{
    switch(param.kernel_type)
    {
        case LINEAR:
            return dot(x,y);
        case POLY:
            return powi(param.gamma*dot(x,y)+param.coef0,param.degree);
        case RBF:
        {
            double sum = 0;
            while(x->index != -1 && y->index !=-1)
            {
                if(x->index == y->index)
                {
                    double d = x->value - y->value;
                    sum += d*d;
                    ++x;
                    ++y;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(x->index > y->index)
                    {
                        sum += y->value * y->value;
                        ++y;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sum += x->value * x->value;
                        ++x;
                    }
                }
            }

            while(x->index != -1)
            {
                sum += x->value * x->value;
                ++x;
            }

            while(y->index != -1)
            {
                sum += y->value * y->value;
                ++y;
            }

            return exp(-param.gamma*sum);
        }
        case SIGMOID:
            return tanh(param.gamma*dot(x,y)+param.coef0);
        case PRECOMPUTED:  //x: test (validation), y: SV
            return x[(int)(y->value)].value;
        default:
            return 0;  // Unreachable 
    }
}

    double kernel_linear(int i, int j) const
    {
        return dot(x[i],x[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Where's `dot` called from?  You're walking one or both of you pointer past the end of allocated memory.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It's called from the LibSVM library after calling svm_predict. It's art of the algorithm. Just added it to the edit. Which one do you think is walking past the allocated memory?

Comment: You aren't checking the return from malloc? If malloc cannot allocate the requested memory this will return nullptr and you will get a SEGV when you try to access the memory.

Comment: @Ben from malloc'ing which variable? Which one should I be checking?

Comment: @Roham All of them. SIGSEGV. invalid memory access (segmentation fault)

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

I had a very hard time finding any documentation about libSVM in c++. So my answer is mostly based on the code you showed us without real reference documentation.

If you could post a link to your documentation it would be very helpful :)

**Potential issue**

You showed the code where you initialize the `svm_node*` in your training code:

```
prob.x[i][mDimension].index = -1;
```

You're initializing an `svm_problem`instance. And apparently in your `dot()` function you expect to see such nodes with a negative index to mark the end of the `svm_node` list.

But you code fails when called like this:

```
Kernel::k_function(x,model->SV[i],model->param);
```

Here, `model` is an `svm_model`, not an `svm_problem`, so I guess this is returned by the libSVM *after* you trained the model. Are you sure the `svm_model` follows the convention of using `node->index = -1` to mark the end of the node list ?

So maybe the marker node just doesn't exist and you run out of bound.

**Why does it break suddenly for 409 items**

The signal you get is a SIGSEGV which indicates that you tried to access a byte in a page not mapped in your process.

When accessing items out of bound you usually don't get a SIGSEGV, because the previously allocated item is in the middle of a memory page, and there are enough bytes after it in the page. It may happens that the 409th item was just after the currently allocated page, triggering the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in 'dot' function, and I solved by not including '0' as a value. As @fjardon mentioned, the function is expecting an index of '-1' and a value of '0' to mark the end of the list of svm_nodes (training vector).

For sure it is a bit late for you but hopefully it will help future libsvm users :)